# MSBuild Delete task works only if Message is present

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have an msbuild 2017 fragment:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BuiltProjects Include="oscript" />
    <BuiltProjects Include="TestApp" />
    <ExcludedArtifacts Include="$(BinFolder)/*.pdb" />
    <ExcludedArtifacts Include="$(BinFolder)/*.xml" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/src/%(BuiltProjects.Identity)/bin/x86/$(Configuration)/net452/**"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(BinFolder)" />
<!-- WITHOUT next Message following Delete is not working! %) -->
<Message Text="@(ExcludedArtifacts)"/>
<Delete Files="@(ExcludedArtifacts)"/>
```

If I delete the Message (marked with comment) then Delete tasks deletes nothing. And nothing about delete is printed on build log. But if I insert this Message element then NO message is printed on log, but deletion starts to work, it prints "deleting file X" and does all the deletion stuff.

What the hell is happening?

Comment: Are those all in the same target? Are you expecting the items copied in the Copy task to be included in the ExcludedArtifacts and thus removed by the Delete task?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's the same target. Copy task copies all the project stuff and also a bunch of *.pdb and *.xml files. I want to remove them (and only them) from final destination. Thus I want to delete them from the destination folder.

Comment: What about not copying them to begin with by excluding them from SourceFiles?

Comment: First I was trying exactly this. But they were "included" anyway. Then I decided,okay, I'll delete them later. They weren't deleted. Then I added a Message, just for debug reasons, wanted to see what is stored in $(ExcludedArtifacts). And voila! Deletion happened. But confusion had remained )